# Let $A,B$ be $2$ square matrices such that $A+AB-2B=0$. Prove $2$ isn't an eigenvalue of $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B$ be $2$ square matrices such that $A+AB-2B=0$. Prove $2$ isn't an eigenvalue of $A$.
I tried assuming the contrary, then there exists $v$ such that $Av=2v$. I multiply both sides of the given equation by $v$ and we get $Av+ABv-2Bv=0$ which implies $2v+ABv-2Bv=0$ and $ABv-2Bv=-2v$, $(A-2I)Bv=-2v$ which means $-2$ is an eigenvalue of $(A-2I)B$. Not sure how to continue.

Comment: Why not look at a left-2-eigenvector $w^T$?

Comment: Proof if B is invertible: Right multiply  $A+AB-2B$ by $B^{-1}$. Then assume 2 is an eigenvalue of A. Then $AB^{-1}=0$. Right multiply by $B$ to get $A=0$, but this contradicts A having non-zero eigenvalues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that since the matrices are square, $A$ and $A^T$ have the same eigenvalues.

In particular for $v\neq 0$ such that $A^Tv=2v$ then

$$A^Tv+B^TA^Tv-2B^Tv=2v+2B^Tv-2B^Tv=2v\neq 0$$

which is a contradiction with $A^T+B^TA^T-2B^T=0$

Answer (score 6):

$A+AB-2B=0$

$A+AB-2B-2I=-2I$

$(A-2I)(B+I)=-2I$

$\therefore A-2I$ is non-singular.

$\therefore$ for any $v \neq 0,$

$(A-2I)v \neq 0$

$Av \neq 2v$

$\therefore 2$ cannot be an eigenvalue.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track: When we obtain
$$
2v + ABv - 2Bv = 0,
$$
we have almost proven the claim. The idea is, however, to consider the transposed $A^\top$ instead of $A$. Then you should use the fact, that they have the same Eigenvalues, i.e., since A has Eigenvalue 2, the same holds true for its transposed $A^\top$, and we call $w$ the corresponding Eigenvector.

Now your desired contradiction follows by transposing the equation and then multiplying with w from the right.